# Edge Limiting is sharing the hits across windows

Tags: 3scale

I have configured the edge limiting policy (Fixed window limiters) for a service that has 2 Rest APIs and each has a different rate limit configured. But while hitting the first API the limit is getting affected for both the APIs.

##### Version: 3.8.0

###### Steps To Reproduce

1. Configuration:

```
"policy_chain": [
  {
    "name": "rate_limit",
    "version": "builtin",
    "configuration": {
      "limits_exceeded_error": {
        "status_code": 429,
        "error_handling": "exit"
      },
      "configuration_error": {
        "status_code": 500,
        "error_handling": "exit"
      },
      "fixed_window_limiters": [
        {
          "window": 60,
          "condition": {
            "combine_op": "and",
            "operations": [
              {
                "op": "==",
                "right": "/first-endpoint",
                "left_type": "liquid",
                "left": "{{uri}}",
                "right_type": "plain"
              }
            ]
          },
          "key": {
            "scope": "service",
            "name": "{{ jwt.sub }}",
            "name_type": "liquid"
          },
          "count": 10
        },
        {
          "window": 60,
          "condition": {
            "combine_op": "and",
            "operations": [
              {
                "op": "==",
                "right": "/second-endpoint",
                "left_type": "liquid",
                "left": "{{uri}}",
                "right_type": "plain"
              }
            ]
          },
          "key": {
            "scope": "service",
            "name": "{{ jwt.sub }}",
            "name_type": "liquid"
          },
          "count": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

2. Hit both endpoints sequentially 21 times in a minute.

###### Current Result

| Endpoint | Value Configured | Hits Allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /first-endpoint | 10 | 5 |
| /second-endpoint | 20 | 15 |

The 6th hit of the `first-endpoint` fails and gives `429 too many requests` and the 16th hit of the `second-endpoint` fails and gives `429 too many requests`.

###### Expected Result

| Endpoint | Value Configured | Hits Allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /first-endpoint | 10 | 10 |
| /second-endpoint | 20 | 20 |

The 11th hit of the `first-endpoint` should fail and give `429 too many requests` and the 21st hit of the `second-endpoint` should fail and give `429 too many requests`

###### Limit reducing pattern

| Hits | /first-endpoint (limit after hit) | /second-endpoint (limit after hit) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 18 |
| 2 | 6 | 16 |
| 3 | 4 | 14 |
| 4 | 2 | 12 |
| 5 | 0 | 10 |
| 6 | too many requests | 9 |
| 7 | too many requests | 8 |
| 8 | too many requests | 7 |
| 9 | too many requests | 6 |
| 10 | too many requests | 5 |
| 11 | too many requests | 4 |
| 12 | too many requests | 3 |
| 13 | too many requests | 2 |
| 14 | too many requests | 1 |
| 15 | too many requests | 0 |
| 16 | too many requests | too many requests |